# Atiyah–Singer Index theorem for the pedestrian / layperson

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, index-theory

So I came across the so-called Atiyah–Singer Index Theorem (ASIT) and claims of it being an extremely powerful and versatile tool.

> **Question.** *What is a truly simple application of the ASIT to obtain a **nontrivial result**, which (i.e the application) requires the least amount of specialized mathematics?*

Thus, ideally the problem should only include basic tools from analysis, algebra (finite linear algebra, group theory), topology. Just elementary stuff.

Comment: Probably the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. Or is this not nontrivial enough?

Comment: two examples are described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/815516/87355

Comment: Jon Hillman has an argument using Atiyah-Singer that excludes certain 3-manifolds from smoothly embedding in $S^4$.  As far as I am aware, it is the only available argument, but this result might be derivable from some Heegaard-Floer machinery, not too far into the future.

Comment: @RyanBudney: which argument are you referring to? Is it published?

Comment: He has a few papers.  The first is: 
J.S.Crisp, J.A.Hillman: Embedding Seifert fibred 3-manifolds and Sol-manifolds in 4-space, Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 76 (1998), 685–710.

If I recall the others I'll add another comment.

Comment: My recollection is Jon's argument is analogous to the Massey argument he cites.  Massey gave a proof of Whitney's conjecture on the possible normal bundles for surfaces embedded in $S^4$.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Thanks for the references. I'm familiar with Massey's argument: it only uses the G-signature theorem in dimension 4, which can also be proved "by hand", without using the index theorem.

Comment: Thanks to all, for the helpful references.